# In a Java project, on IntelliJ Idea, does a faster way exist to list Java sources in their packages than the one I'm using?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I enjoy the view listing *Java* sources in their flatten packages, under *IntelliJ Idea 2022.3.2*.

But, due to some settings or lack of knowledge, it takes me a lot of manipulations to reach the display I'm looking for, each time I'm considering some project sources.

1. I'm willing to see the sources of that central project, so I'm opening it:

[image]

2. Then, I do a second click of my mouse, on the `src` folder:

[image]

3. Then, a third one on the `main` folder:

[image]

4. Then, a fourth one on the `java` folder:

[image]

and here the *Java* sources are conveniently listed, the way I like them to be.

**But it took me a lot of mouse clicks.

What's the way to reach here without doing so many ones?**

(I don't want to use the *Expand All* toolbar button at the top of the Project View, that would open all the projects).

Comment: Have you tried the `Package` view (click the `Project` text in the Project tool window and choose the `Pacakge` to switch to it)? There is also a related feature request here that could help your use case https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107947 though it is not supported yet.

Comment: @LJreplica It's an interesting display, already, and I think it might be good enough for me atm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the parent node (SparkDatasetCatalogue...), then use the "Find Action" command (`CMD+SHIFT+A` or `CTRL+SHIFT+A`), then search for "Full Expand Tree Node" and hit `Enter`.

[image: Find Actions dialog]

I do this often enough that I assigned it to a shortcut (I used `CMD+SHIFT+8`). You can assign it to a shortcut right in the "Find Action" dialog by pressing `OPTION+ENTER` (I think it's `ALT+ENTER` on Windows). Or you can go into the key mapping preferences and assign it there.